# Simple query to firebase database returning very large response

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to do a very simple query by following the instructions at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries by doing something like this:

```
const requestQueueRef = db.collection('brocasters').doc('Kala').collection('requestQueue')
var querye = requestQueueRef.where("id", "==","0wEMRQYh3D5ODHJN6kThyO")
```

What I am trying to do is prevent duplicate IDs from being stored in requestQueue so I am checking for the id before inserting a new document (I hard coded the id for this example).

When I examine the `querye` variable, I have a very large response (5821 lines of JSON). But what's making me think I am doing something wrong is that if I change the `.where("id", "==","0wEMRQYh3D5ODHJN6kThyO")` part to some gibberish like `.where("iddddd", "==","aaaaaa0wEMRQYh3D5ODHJN6kThyO")` I still get a very large response.

Comment: is that literally all the code u are using? it seems incompleted

Comment: Your `querye` variable is a [`firebase.firestore.Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query.html). This is **not** actual data but an object that you can use to read from and listen to. You might want to call its [`get()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query.html#get)

Answer (score 2):

The code you're showing hasn't yet performed a query.  What you're probably doing is dumping JSON formatted representation of the Query object you built.  If you want to actually perform the query, you should do something like call `get()` on the query object you built, then examine the results provided in a QuerySnapshot.

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) on queries to get more details on querying Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing some part of the code, this should do the trick:

```
const requestQueueRef = db.collection('brocasters').doc('Kala').collection('requestQueue')
var querye = requestQueueRef
    .where("id", "==","0wEMRQYh3D5ODHJN6kThyO")
    .get()
    .then((snap) => {
     snap.docs.forEach(doc => {
       if(doc.exists) console.log(doc.data())
     })
    })
```